# How can I preserve fixed width display while hiding/showing span elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with some code from [BioJS](https://github.com/Arabidopsis-Information-Portal/biojs1/blob/master/src/main/javascript/Biojs.Sequence.js) of which I'd like to extend the functionality. A BioJS object forms a sequence display by creating a separate span element for each letter and creating a break after x number of letters as such (simplified):

```
`   var j=1;
    for (var i=1; i <= a.length; i++) {

        if( i % opt.numCols == 0) {
            str += '<span class="sequence" id="' + this.getId() + '_' + i + '">' + a[i-1] + '</span>';

            str += '<br/>';

            j = 1;

        } else {
            str += '<span class="sequence" style="'+spaceStyle+'" id="' + this.getId() + '_' + i + '">' + a[i-1];
            str += ( j % opt.numColsForSpace == 0)? ' ' : '';
            str += (opt.spaceBetweenChars)? ' ' : '';
            str += '</span>';
            j++;
        }
    }`
```

This is nice for the built-in functionality of adding highlights to specific coordinates, which just uses jQuery to find the appropriate span and change the css. I've tried to take a similar approach with hiding elements by changing them to display:none, but unfortunately this leaves the line breaks behind, and thus big holes in the text. See a picture here: 
[Showing/Hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsBiw.png)

I'd like to know if there is another way I could create a similar display that would allow me to retain the fixed-width output after hiding the elements. Ideally I would still be able to use the highlight function, but I could also re-code that as well to work in a different way.

Comment: It's unclear what you're issue is, but `display:none` will hide an element, and also cause the layout to reflow as though it never existed. `visibility:hidden` will visually hide an element, but leave its space in the document flow.

Comment: I'm already using display:none. However, the line breaks are preserved because they're inserted by the javascript. If I remove these line breaks, then I'm left with a series of span elements which overflow the parent div on the right side. Perhaps there's some CSS setting or a different type of element that can be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, which was that the javascript from BioJS was adding an inline style of `whitespace: pre` that was preventing the span elements from wrapping within the container. It was causing the containing element to only break on line breaks.